# Is there a way how I can run code on multiple threads so it gets executed faster and then wait for all of them to complete?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have 2 functions, I need the first one to be completed first and then the second, but running it on one thread took a long time so I tried running it like with CoroutineScope, but the second function executes even if not all images are downloaded.

```
downloadSkillsImages(context)      
addSkillsToDB()
```

```
private suspend fun downloadSkillsImages(context: Context) {
        for (i in 0 until skills.size) {
            CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                try {
                    val url = fbStorage.reference.child("skillImagesMini").child("${skills[i].skillId}.jpg").downloadUrl.await()
                    skills[i].skillImage = getBitmapFromUri(url, context)
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    //image not found, nothing happens
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are `getBitmapFromUri` and `addSkillsToDB` both `suspend` long running functions? Can I see their implementations?

Comment: I agree with @Sergey that it depends, but generic answer is that you should enclose `for` inside `coroutineScope {}` and then replace `CoroutineScope(IO).launch{}` with `launch(IO) {}`.

Comment: ```
suspend fun getBitmapFromUri(source: Uri, context: Context): Bitmap {
            val loading = ImageLoader(context)
            val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(source).build()
            val result = (loading.execute(request) as SuccessResult).drawable
            return (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
}
``` 
this is my first time coding an app in kotlin so i dont really know what i am doing yet, but i had to use a different thread than main to add skills to db, i use room

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `coroutineScope` scope function is for. It waits for all its children coroutines to finish.

```
private suspend fun downloadSkillsImages(context: Context) = coroutineScope {
    for (i in skills.indices) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val url = fbStorage.reference.child("skillImagesMini").child("${skills[i].skillId}.jpg").downloadUrl.await()
                skills[i].skillImage = getBitmapFromUri(url, context)
            } catch (e: Exception){
                //image not found, nothing happens
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you only need to specify Dispatchers.IO if `getBitmapFromUri` is a blocking function. If it's a suspend function, then nothing in this child coroutine is blocking, so it wouldn't matter what dispatcher is used to call it.

Since you want your coroutines to all finish and silently ignore the ones that fail, you can simplify this by using `supervisorScope` instead of `coroutineScope` so you don't need try/catch. `supervisorScope` will complete successfully even if some of its children fail.

```
private suspend fun downloadSkillsImages(context: Context) = supervisorScope {
    for (i in skills.indices) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val url = fbStorage.reference.child("skillImagesMini").child("${skills[i].skillId}.jpg").downloadUrl.await()
            skills[i].skillImage = getBitmapFromUri(url, context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "wouldn't matter what dispatcher is used to call it" - I have been wrapping my API calls in `Dispatchers.IO` in `Repository`. If an API call is `suspend` function and not blocking I/O, can I just let it execute in `Dispatchers.Main` from `viewModelScope`? Does changing dispatcher to IO change anything in this case?

Comment: @rupinderjeet A suspend function must not block. (If your suspend function blocks, you composed it incorrectly). Therefore it's never necessary to specify `Dispatchers.IO` or `Default` just to call a suspend function. However, theoretically you could have a suspend function that calls some functions that are only allowed to be called from the Main thread because they work with UI. In that case, you might have to specify `Dispatchers.Main` to call them, although personally, I would switch to Main internally in the function so it's encapsulated and you can freely use suspend functions anywhere.

Comment: So, in the case you described, specifying the dispatcher is not accomplishing anything. In a more complicated suspend function that does more than just pass through a call to a single other suspend function, then it *does* do something. The non-suspend code you call in the suspend function will be running on whichever dispatcher is currently being used. In most cases, this doesn't matter since it's non-blocking code anyway so you don't care what dispatcher is doing the trivial work. If you did care, you'd wrap it in `withContext` to specify what you do want to be running it.

Comment: I understand. I went through some code on architecture-samples last weekend, especially [these four functions](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/3d71ecfda85d17c9724827685e54017633fc2730/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/DefaultTasksRepository.kt#L111-L139). I haven't explored it much, but I don't understand why 3 of these functions use `ioDispatcher` while all of them access & use same resource - the database. I am curious about the decision-making on what to use. I hope this isn't just a guess on how long/expensive the task is

Comment: I'm not sure. They're allowing the IO dispatcher to be customized which might be something you want to do to if using a different thread pool. But if the upstream class is just a Room DAO, I don't see what it's accomplishing to specify the dispatcher at all. I haven't looked at these architecture samples before, but it's possible they have some errors or sub-optimal practices. I have seen some of Google's Code Labs for Android that have numerous errors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am blindly making all calls, that go through `Repository`, to change dispatcher to `IO` from `Main` using `withContext` in my projects. This is certainly eye-opening to me. I understand that this discussion is not relevant to the question above. So, I thank you for your time. I should explore this more. Perhaps, I will ask them in a github issue this weekend to understand their reasoning. Thank you.